# recv()/send() is out of order after first pass

Tags: c, send, recv

I've made a basic client-server game of tic-tac-toe, and I'm trying to get it to work right. It works perfectly fine one pass through, but once I loop back to try to play again the `recv()` gets out of order (my client is sending things it should have been sending one `send()` command before). 
I've looked at my code for a good hour or so and I can't figure out why.

As you can probably tell I'm new to sockets and TCP programming in general, so I don't know how to approach this.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Example code will be helpful..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted the code, But judging by what you've said..
recv() doesn't ensure that it will read all the data that was sent by send() of other program.
It just returns the number of bytes read. So you'll need to keep the count and ensure tthat you've read it all. 
In a nutshell, You will have to handle the number of bytes read and wrote on both sides using some predefined protocol. I suggest you get a good book on this if you haven't already, it will really help.